# Añadir columnas a una tabla html mediante PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de facturación, en el que al añadir un producto debe crearse una fila nueva con la información del producto que agregó.

Esto debe hacerse cuando el último input pierda el foco, el problema está ahí, no se crea la fila.

Ya probé mostrando con un consol.log la información que viene desde el archivo PHP donde está la consulta para el proceso almacenado y la variable con la que debería agregarse la fila, y efectivamente muestra los datos parseados en JSON.

Sé que es más fácil añadir filas mediante con JS, pero en este caso necesito que se cree la fila ya con los datos en ella. O si esto también se puede hacer un JS me serviría también.

Este es el archivo PHP

```
<?php


include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");
session_start();


if($_POST['action'] == 'addProductoDetalle'){
    if(empty($_POST['codigo']) || empty($_POST['cantidad'])){
        echo "error";
    }else{
        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
        $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
        $token = md5($_SESSION['username']);

        $query_detalle = mysqli_query($conexion, "CALL add_detalle_temp($codigo, $cantidad, '$token')");
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query_detalle);

        echo $result;

        $detalleTabla = '';
        $arrayData = array();

        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_detalle)){
            $subtotal = round($data['cantidad_'] * $data['precio_venta_']);
            $detalleTabla .='<tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="codigo" class="cod" id="codigo">'.$data['id_producto_'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="producto" class="nam" id="descripcion">'.$data['descripcion_'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cantidad" class="can" id="cantidad" value="0">'.$data['cantidad_'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="valor" class="val" id="venta" value="0.00">'.$data['precio_venta_'].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" class="sub" id="subtotal" value="0.00">'.$subtotal.'</td>
            </tr>';
        } 
        $arrayData['detalle'] = $detalleTabla;

        echo json_encode($arrayData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}

?>
```

Esta es la función JS con el Ajax para enviar y recibir la información

```
$('#subtotal').blur(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#codigo').val() > 0) {

            let codigo = $("#codigo").val();
            let cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
            let action = 'addProductoDetalle';

            $.ajax({

                url: '/papeleria/controllers/detalleTemp.controller.php',
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    codigo: codigo,
                    cantidad: cantidad,
                    action: action
                },


                success: function(response) {

                    console.log(response)
                    if (response != 'error') {

                        var info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                        $("#detalle").html(info.detalle)

                    }

                },

                error: function(response) {


                },

            });
        };

    });
```

Esto es lo que contiene la variable response

[image: el console.log]

De verdad les agradezco la ayuda, es para un trabajo y no sé que más hacer :(

También agrego el HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facturación POS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/papeleria/assets/css/styles.css" th:href="@/papeleria/assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/papeleria/assets/css/facturacionpos.css" th:href="@/papeleria/assets/css/fascturacionpos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <?php
        include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/Views/template/header.view.php")
        ?>
    </header>
    <div class="container w-75 p-3">
        <div class="info">
            <form action="post" class="info">
                <div class="id">ID Factura</div><input type="text" class="id-form" name="ID factura">
                <input type="date" class="fecha">
                <div>
                    <?php
                    include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");
                    $query_cli = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes_");
                    $result_cli = mysqli_num_rows($query_cli);

                    ?>
                    <select name="id" class="pro-form cliente">
                        <?php
                        if ($result_cli > 0) {
                            while ($cliente = mysqli_fetch_array($query_cli)) {
                        ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $cliente["id_cliente_"]; ?>"><?php echo $cliente["nombre_"]; ?></option>
                        <?php

                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php
                    include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");
                    $query_us = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios_");
                    $result_us = mysqli_num_rows($query_us);

                    ?>
                    <select class="vendedor pro-form">
                        <?php
                        if ($result_us > 0) {
                            while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($query_us)) {
                        ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $usuario["id_usuario_"]; ?>"><?php echo $usuario["nombre_usuario_"]; ?></option>
                        <?php

                            }
                        }

                        if (isset($_POST['pago'])) {
                            $pago = $_POST['pago'];
                        } else {
                            $pago = '';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="co">Contado</div><input type="checkbox" name="pago" class="con" value="contado" <?php if ($pago == "contado") echo "checked"; ?>>
                <div class="cr">Crédito</div><input type="checkbox" name="pago" class="cre" value="credito" <?php if ($pago == "credito") echo "checked"; ?>>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="factura-container w-75 p-3">
        <div class="form-container">
            <table class="table overflow-auto" id="tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr class="cab">
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="codigo" class="cod" id="codigo"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="producto" class="nam" id="descripcion"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cantidad" class="can" id="cantidad" value="0"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="valor" class="val" id="venta" value="0.00"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" class="sub" id="subtotal" value="0.00"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <div id="detalle">

                </div>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container w-75 p-3">
        <div class="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Cerrar factura</a></li>
                <li><a href="/papeleria/views/imprimir/imprimirfactura.view.php" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nueva factura</a></li>
                <li><a href="" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Reimprimir</a></li>
                <li><a href="" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Pasar a cartera</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="paga">Paga<input type="text" class="paga-form" name="Paga"></div>
            <div class="cambio">Cambio<input type="text" class="cambio-form" name="Cambio"></div>
            <div class="total">Total<input type="text" class="total-form" name="Total"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <?php
        include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/Views/template/footer.view.php")
        ?>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Agrega el HTML para conocer la estructura, da mas contexto a tu pregunta para darte una respuesta mas acertada, recuerda que puedes modificar tu pregunta las veces que quieras.

Comment: Que es lo que sucede?, no pinta la informacio?, te sale error?

Comment: No muestra la información, en el tbody hay un div con el id que debe tomar la función para insertar la fila, pero no lo hace, y tampoco muestra un error ni en la consola ni en el error.log de Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final era algo bastante tonto, en el `$(#detalle).html(info.detalle)` no era necesario poner el `.detalle`

Answer (score 0):

Observando tu código creo que el problema puede estar en una de estas dos partes, en tu **html** debes agregar el script de **js** donde estas llevando acabo la petición ajax, la cual no observo, si esta, indicamela. Por otra parte modifica tu ajax, indicandole a la petición el tipo de dato que pretendes recibir, en esta caso es de tipo *JSON*, ejemplo:

```js
$('#subtotal').blur(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  if ($('#codigo').val() > 0) {

    let codigo = $("#codigo").val();
    let cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
    let action = 'addProductoDetalle';

    $.ajax({

      url: '/papeleria/controllers/detalleTemp.controller.php',
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      //Indicamos el tipo de dato a recibir
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
        codigo: codigo,
        cantidad: cantidad,
        action: action,

      },
      //Comprobamos antes de enviar la petición
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert('Enviando datos'),
      },
      //Si se cumple la petición pintamos en 'detalle'
      success: function(response) {

        console.log(response)
        $("#detalle").html(response);
      },

      //Comprobamos si la petición no se pudo realizar
      error: function(response) {
        alert('Error al realizar la petición');
      },

    });
  };

});
```

La data que retorna PHP en el **succes** de Ajax la quieres validar con IF, no entiendo para que, ya que todo el procesamiento y condicionales lo llevas acabo en PHP, así que no tiene caso a menos que usaras **estatus**, pero no es el caso. Recuerda que Ajax tomara como respuesta todo lo que imprimas con **echo de PHP**, el error procesalo también en PHP, dime si funciono.

Comment: Con la nueva función me aparece este error: Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\papeleria\\Controllers\\detalleTemp.controller.php:16\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\papeleria\\Controllers\\detalleTemp.controller.php(16): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'CALL add_detall...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\papeleria\\Controllers\\detalleTemp.controller.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/papeleria/views/facturaci%C3%B3n/facturacionpos.view.php

Comment: Creo que hace referencia a que estas incluyendo un script php dos veces, revisa tus include en caso de que se el caso utiliza **include_once**, para que se incluya solo una vez y no arroje error.

Comment: Había un error en la consulta, sin embargo sigue sin pintar la información :(

Comment: ok, que **version de PHP** estas utilizando?, es necesario utilizar **JSON**?

Comment: La 8.1.4. No sé si sea más fácil añadir la fila con JS y extraer los datos del archivo .php, o sea que PHP no tenga que enviar el html si no los valores de las variables solamente

Comment: Mira, puedes generar el código HTML desde el back PHP o desde el mismo ajax en el succes, el problema se presenta en el ajax por el tipo de dato JSON, ya que tu estas agregando a tu response HTML. Procesa el array data en php sin HTML, solo recorrelo, guárdalo en un array y en js generamos el HTML. Dime si quieres un ejemplo.

Comment: Mira en este github empecé la estructura, ya se añaden las filas pero sale como indefinida la variable, dime que tendría que modificar, https://github.com/MCasas18/Facturacion